# Laravel, get all objects related to a polymorphic resource while using select() to filter out some fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have a polymorphic Category model and an articles model I want to get all articles within a category and use select() so I don't have to get the article body(for performance)

**in my articles model I have:**

```
public function categories(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Category::class, 'categorizable');
}
```

**and in my Category model I have:**

```
  public function articles(): MorphToMany
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Articles', 'categorizable');
    }
```

**my implementation to get articles within a category:**

```
 public function getArticleByCategory(Request $request)
    {
        $cat = $request->q;
        try {
            $category = Category::where('cat_slug', $cat)->first();
            $articles = null;
            if ($category) {
                $articles = $category->articles()
                    ->with('author:id,full_name,user_name,avatar')
                    ->with('categories:id,cat_name,cat_slug')
                    ->select('fields i want to retrieve')
                    ->paginate(15);
            }
            if ($articles) {
                return $this->sendResponse($articles, "All articles in " . $cat, 200);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->sendError(ErrorType::SERVER_ERROR, 'A server error occurred, we are sorry for the inconvenience', 500);
        }
    }
```

the issue with this is that even though I select certain fields all the fields are being returned which I don't want